# How is non-deprecated different enum type comparison supposed to be conducted?

Tags: c++, enums, deprecation-warning

I have this piece of template code somewhere within a template class with template types S,T:

```cpp
using answer_type = Flag<( (std::is_same_v<S,T>) and (s==t) )>;
```

Clang says:

```
warning: comparison of different enumeration types is deprecated.
```

So GPT proposes I create one metric ton of boilerplate to prevent the comparison:

```cpp
template <typename S, typename T, S s, T t>
struct is_same_and_equal {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T, T s, T t>
struct is_same_and_equal<T, T, s, t> {
    static constexpr bool value = s == t;
};
```

so that

```cpp
using answer_type = Flag< is_same_and_equal<S, T, s, t>::value >;
```

Now, since this is marked as deprecated, is there an equally short-as-original solution that is non-deprecated? Why exactly is the original solution disadvantageous? (Is it even?)

### Remark

The application is: "If T enum type Color and S is enum type Material" then return false. If both types are Color or material then compare their markedness.

Comment: Would something like `using answer_type = Flag<( (std::is_same_v<S,T>) and ((int)s==(int)t) )>;` do it? (Presuming S and T can both be cast to `int`.)

Comment: This is _GENIOUS_, since I am only ever using enum types and constrain that accordingly. Thank you a lot! (though I leave the question when the deprecation also extends to non-enum kinds)

Comment: why is `using answer_type = Flag< is_same_and_equal<S, T, s, t>::value >;`  "marked as deprecated" ? I triggers the same warning from clang?

Comment: can you post a [mcve] ? I am not able to reproduce it. In particular, I am not sure what `s` and `t` are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use *constexpr-if* to avoid the comparison in case `S` and `T` are not the same type:

```cpp
template<class S, class T, S s, T t>
auto foo() {
    using answer_type = Flag<[]{if constexpr (std::is_same_v<S,T>) return s == t;
                                else return false;}()>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this meets your case:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum S {};
enum T {};

template <bool> struct Flag {};

template <S s, T t>
struct foo {
    using answer_type = Flag<( (std::is_same_v<S,T>) and (s==t) )>;
};
```

If it does, you can cast either of the two to the other type. You already know that they are of same type:

```
using answer_type = Flag<( (std::is_same_v<S,T>) and (s==static_cast<S>(t)) )>;
```

Its a bit of a hack to silence the warning, because `and` is short cuirciting and `s` and `t` are constant expressions, hence no enums of different type are compared. The compiler isnt trying to be too clever to realize what `std::is_same` actually does, its a trait like others, hence its not obvious that it returns `false` when `S` and `T` are different types.

Comment: looks very similar to casting both to int, which is what I go with :)

Comment: @mhawth36 depending on what `S` and `T` are and what their underlying type is casting to `int` can be wrong